# Linker problems when linking to static libraries instead of shared ones

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a C++ application (`app`) which links to a shared C++ library A (`libA`) which links to a static C library B (`libB`). With this configuration my application compiles and links just fine.
Now, if I decide to make `libA` a static library, I get a linker error during the `app` linking. It says: "error: undefined reference to `mpfit`". `mpfit` is a function in `libB`. If I do `nm libA` I get:

```
libA.cpp.o:
             // ... blah blah ...
             U mpfit
             // ... blah blah ...
```

`libA.cpp` is a file belonging to the `libA` library.

I configure the build using CMake, and the configuration of the static version of `libA` is exactly the same with the configuration of the shared version of `libA`.

Any idea what is going on here? Why by just switching from a shared to a static library causes a linker error?

Comment: What is the order in which you pass the libraries to the linker? Could you try to switch them?

Comment: Do you provide `libB.a` as well as `libA.a` when linking `app`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I did not provide libB.a when linking the app. I tried it and it worked! However, I thought that CMake is supposed to do that automatically. No? I guess that is a different question though...